# Should the "automated switch" questions be merged?

Tags: discussion

There are two questions about switches that can be electronically or mechanically actuated:

[Switch that can be remotely switched](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59927/switch-that-can-be-remotely-switched)

[Is there such a thing as a switch that can be actuated automatically?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102808/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-switch-that-can-be-actuated-automatically/102840#102840)

We could mark one as duplicate of the other, but the answers in both are relevant and useful.

Is this worth a merge, duplicate, or should we just add comments to each pointing to the other as a possible resource?

Answer (score 1):

**just add comments to each pointing to the other as a possible resource**